# How would I improve/enable audio on games running through crosh?

Tags: audio, google-chrome-os

Using [Chromebrew](https://github.com/chromebrew/chromebrew) on my Acer Spin 713, I installed Flatpak with `crew install flatpak`. Using Flatpak, I installed Lutris and it runs great. I ran into the issue of game execution, but I just remounted the `/home` directory from `noexec` to `exec` and now it runs perfectly... for the most part. The audio is *pretty bad* for Factorio and doesn't even work for Minecraft (using ATLauncher). Does anyone have any suggestions on why it isn't working? I can't think of why and I don't really know where to look. There isn't much information on the web about gaming on a Chromebook without using Crostini or dual-boot.

EDIT:
After getting the suggestion from Arctiic, I did some testing and my conclusion is the Linux apps use the PulseAudio library, which is unsupported by ChromeOS. My new question would be how to make PulseAudio compatible with ChromeOS Audio Server (CrAS).

Comment: Never used it myself, but isn't audio troubleshooting done through `cras`?

Comment: @Arctiic I'll test that out. That is probably the missing key.